# How to move mailer inside namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I've got a Rails 3 mailer that works fine.

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  def cool_email(user_id)
     @user = User.find_by_id(user_id)
     mail(to: @user.email,
          from: 'admin@example.com',            
          subject: 'hi'
       )
    end 
 end
```

The view for this will render the @user instance variable correctly and the email is sent without any problem.

However, when I namespace the mailer, everything breaks.  With the mailer structured like this.

```
class Foo::Notifier < ::ActionMailer::Base
  def cool_email(user_id)
     @user = User.find_by_id(user_id)
     mail(to: @user.email,
          from: 'admin@example.com',            
          subject: 'hi'
       )
    end 
 end
```

And the view inside app/view/foo, Rails is unable to find the html template.  The email sends, but there is nothing inside the body.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The views should be stored in `app/view/foo/notifier`, specifically `app/view/foo/notifier/cool_email.EXTENSION`.

FYI, it's always a good practice to append `Mailer` to the name of a mailer.

```
class Foo::NotifierMailer < ::ActionMailer::Base
```

or

```
class Foo::NotificationMailer < ::ActionMailer::Base
```

It prevents conflicts and makes possible to immediately understand the scope of the class.

Comment: This still doesn't fix the problem.  `app/views/foo/notifier/cool_email.html.erb` Still does not get rendered.

Comment: Dude, I was the problem.  I was in console and getting a new stnace of cool_email, but I wasn't appending the deliver method, so that's why I thought I the template wasn't rendering.  TL;DR: I'm an idiot.